# Adding ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks.dll to Toolbox causes 'could not load file or assembly' error

Tags: msbuild, workflow-activity, custom-activity

I am adding [this](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/2013/02/custom-build-task-include-merged.html) custom build task to my TFS 2010 build workflow, however when attempting to add it (`ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks.dll`) to the toolbox, I get error:

`'Could not load file or assembly file 'ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported'`.

I have added all of its dependencies to (I admit, this is probably redundant):

1) the same location where the `ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks.dll` resides, which is ..\BuildProcessTemplates\CustomActivities

2) in the Public Assemblies folder: `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

And I have the build definition xaml file correctly importing the `ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks` namespace

Although the activity is set to target .Net 4.5, the [documentation](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Including%20merges%20%28and%20associated%20work%20items%29%20in%20a%20build&referringTitle=Documentation) says that TFS 2010 / .Net 4.0 is supported, so I assume this should all be possible.

**My Questions:**

**Is this possible with TFS 2010 / .Net 4.0 development environment?** My concern is that the error message isn't telling the real story, for example maybe it is able to find it, however just not the right *version* of the assembly.

**Is it likely that since the DLL targets .Net 4.5 I need to have all of its referenced dll's also be the 4.5 version?** For example, it references `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` however I only have the version 10.0.0.0 (which I assume the .Net 4.5 version of this might be 11.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution, in short story format: I installed Visual Studio 2012. Result: I was able to add ColinsALMCorner.CustomBuildTasks to my workflow in Visual Studio 2010 without error. I assume this means there was a 2012 (v11.0.0.0) DLL or two required to use the activity in 2010, despite the fact that the requirements state:

Team Foundation Build 2010, 2012 or 2013